# HtmlAgility with SignalR for continuous web audit

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, html-agility-pack

I am trying to build a web crawler, where, on entering the primary URL it will update you if any link is broken on that domain. Instead of auditing the URL on button click, I would like it to update regularly such as whenever the link is broken it shows on dashboard.

For this, I try to use the SignalR with HtmlAgility. This is my code in the SignalR Hub:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace scanUrl
{
    public class TestHub : Hub
    {

        public void PopulateTreeView(string aURL, int parentId, TreeNode treeNode, TreeView tvURL)
        {
            HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(aURL);
            foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
            {
                HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];

                if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(att.Value, UriKind.Absolute))
                {
                    TreeNode child = new TreeNode
                    {
                        Text = att.Value,
                        Value = att.Value
                    };
                    if (parentId == 0)
                    {
                        tvURL.Nodes.Add(child);
                        PopulateTreeView(aURL, int.Parse(child.Value), child, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Clients.All.treeNode.ChildNodes.Add(child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a treeview control on my .aspx page that shall be filled/loaded from the signalR Hub class, but how can I make this process continuous?

Comment: Well you have to do it with JS and AJAX

Comment: Thanks, was helpful (y), if you could provide any reference URL, that would be amazing